# GitHub API limit exceeded: how to increase the rate limit in front-end apps

Tags: web-applications, frontend, github-api

After some HTTP requests to the GitHub API, it starts refusing the calls saying:

> API rate limit exceeded for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. (But here's the good
>   news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the
>   documentation for more details.)

Now, there is [a way to increase the unauthenticated rate limit for OAuth applications](https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications) which involves using the `client secret`.

Of course we don't want to put or `client secret` on the public source code of a front-end app, as also the documentation recommends:

> Note: Never share your client secret with anyone or include it in client-side browser code. Use the method shown here only for server-to-server calls.

so I was wondering what's the best way to solve the issue of the rate limit in a front end application.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite old question, however I managed to extend the limit from 60 to 5000. I am putting the `client_secret` to `Header:Authorization` - it is my private app, so I do not care about the security. Looking for the solution I have found that you can put `mode='cors'` to `initRequest` and you are able to send `CORS` request to GitHub API.

TypeScript class example:
Typscript simple class exmaple
e.g:

```
export default class AppRequestInit implements RequestInit {

  public method: string = 'GET';
  public headers: Headers = new Headers();
  public mode: RequestMode = 'cors';

  constructor() {
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  }
}

usage: fetch('https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME', new AppRequestInit())
```